# ASP MVC 3 - Images not showing on first page view - but often on a refresh

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have seen loads of questions about images not showing but mine seems to be intermittent,  Often the image does not appear on the first page view but will be there following a refresh.  I am using a JQuery plugin to pop some text up on an image hover.

Here is an HTML snippet (I actually have three images but have added only one here):

```
<div class="container_24 spacing-bot">
<ul id="topGallery" class="image-overlay">
    <li>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Wedding")">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/photos/image_one.png")" width="290" height="433" alt="Image One."/>
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Heading One</h3>
                <p>Pop up comment one.</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>       
</ul>
```

The JQuery code at the botton of the page is:

```
$("#topGallery")
  .ImageOverlay({ 
    border_color: "#000", 
    overlay_color: "#0545F5", 
    overlay_origin: "bottom", 
    overlay_text_color: "#fff", 
    overlay_speed: 'fast', 
    overlay_speed_out : 'slow' });
```

The images display every time on my development machine but not on the production server.  I checked the page with Firebug and the images seem to be coming down.  Often when I refresh the page or go back to it from somewhere else, the images appear as normal.  Sometimes one or two of the images will appear fine but the other wont.

Any assistance would be appreciated - this one is driving me loopy!

Comment: If you don't use the jQuery plugin do the images show up every time?

Comment: +1 for @pjumble. Remove the extra "stuff" first and see if things work. If they do, then you figured out where your problem is happening. If it doesn't work, then you can continue to dig down.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion. I removed all the jQuery stuff and the images appeared every time.

I carried on researching this and found someone else who had the same problem. They resolved it by putting the jQuery code into the window.load function and this appears to have fixed my problem too.

I assume there is some code in the constructor for this plugin that sets the visibility of the images and this was failing if the images were not loaded at the time. This probably also explains why it would often work after a refresh or when returning to the page as the images were cached.

Thanks again.